# How to hide the div until the page load then show after the page completely loaded?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to hide the div till page load the i want show that div after the page is completely loaded, for that in my phtml file i tried this.

```
<div id='pilot' style="display : none">
    <div class="trustpilot-widget" data-locale="en-US" data-template-id="5406e6b0d049e042d5f" data-      businessunit-id="54c2a000ff00057c" data-style-height="28px" data-style-width="100%" data-theme="light">
<a href="https://www.trustpilot.com/review/www.mani.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Trustpilot</a>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#pilot").show();
});
</script>
```

But its not working, any help can be appreciated.

Comment: Your code seems working fine,what's your problem?

Comment: Did u include `jquery` like `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>` ?

Comment: Hi Cositanto, no.

Comment: Hi  lucumt, it not showing the div after the page load.

Comment: _Hi Cositanto, no._ Does that mean you didnt load the jQuery library

Comment: `jQuery` would be a slight overkill if this is all you need, just do-> `document.querySelector("#pilot").style.display = 'block';`   You don't even need the ready event, just place the script before your `</body>` closing tag.   Although to be fair, even after doing this I don't think it's going to do what your after, I assume your wanting to wait for TrustPilot to load, that's not the same as waing for the document to load, there could a lot of differed loading the Trust Pilot widget, you might want to see if there is an event you can attach to that instead.

Comment: check the error in `console` and add `console.log` inside `ready` function.

Comment: Reading the Docs on Trust Pilot -> `The small script doesn't fetch the widget content until your page has loaded. `  IOW: waiting for the page to load is not going to help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If your jQuery library is loaded in to the DOM and you can't see any errors on the console, then this code should work for 100% sure.
2. If this is your content all on the page, that will be rendered during milliseconds, so your jQuery code will be executed in no time. Make delayed showing the DIV, and in that case will seem like loaded after the page rendered.